# Django Custom User model not updating

Tags: python, django

I have a custom user model with subclassing AbstractUser
I want to update it with an Update view

models.py:

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def New_Requests(self):
        return super.get_queryset().filter(is_seller="I")

class User(AbstractUser):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="Nick Name",default='User')
    is_seller_status = (
                        ('N','Not accepted'),
                        ('I','Investigate'),
                        ('A','Accepted')
                        )
    is_seller = models.CharField(default='N',max_length=1,choices=is_seller_status,verbose_name='seller')
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default = uuid.uuid4,editable = False,unique=True)
    profile = models.ImageField(upload_to="user_profile",blank=True,null=True)
    admin_reject_reason = models.TextField(default='Not reviewed yet')
```

views.py:

```
class AccountView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = "user/profile.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("user:profile")

    def get_object(self):
        return User.objects.get(pk = self.request.user.pk)
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AccountView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user  # Pass 'user' directly to the form
        return kwargs
```

forms.py:

```
class UserProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    #User profileform
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not user.is_superuser:
            self.fields['first_name'].disabled = True
            self.fields['last_name'].disabled = True
            #self.fields['email'].help_text = "Change it if it was neccessary"
            self.fields['email'].disabled = True
            self.fields['is_seller'].disabled = True
        
    class Meta:
        #specifing the model and fields
        model = User
        fields = ['profile','nickname','username','email','first_name','last_name',
            'is_seller']
```

urls.py:

```
app_name = "user"

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('profile/',AccountView.as_view(),name='profile'),
    ...
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`
```

profile.html:

```
{% extends 'user/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <!-- Begin Page Content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
                    
        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Profile</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class = "card card-primary">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class = "card-title mb-0 float-left">User Update</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                {{ form.first_name|as_crispy_field }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                {{ form.last_name|as_crispy_field }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                {{ form.is_seller|as_crispy_field }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                {{ form.profile|as_crispy_field }}
                            </div>         
                        </div>
                        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Update">
                        
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->


<!-- End of Main Content -->
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "user.User"
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "user.User"
```

and I have the app installed

When ever I hit the update button it reloades the page and the changes apply in the template not in database
If you open a page the information that it display's is not updated
I'm using django 4.2.8 btw

Comment: Your Profile model is your User model?  are you using django-profiletools?  Something seems off here,  usually a "profile" is a seperate model that you One to One FK to.  Can you show your UserProfileForm code?

Comment: You also might want to extend the form_invalid method on the update view and print out form.errors

Comment: Also, I know this doesn't relate to your original question but that Manager is completely broke,  your calling super (missing parenthesis) inside a custom method, on a built in method.  I think you wanted self.get_queryset().

Comment: just a heads up, user = kwargs.pop('user')  will break if you ever use this form without passing user through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the nickname in form fields but you don't use it inside the template.

You haven't set `blank=True` for the `nickname` model field, so when you send the form data without nickname value you get `"This field is required"` error for that field. (you can check this by overriding `form_invalid` method and printing errors)

You can do one of these:

1- add `blank=True` in your nickname model field

2- add nickname field inside your template

3- just delete it from your form fields if you don't need to it

Answer (score 0):

According to django-profiletools (which I think you are using here?) you should define
`AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "profiles.Profile"`
which points to your profile model which should look something like

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Yours is just pointing to your User model and it appears you just have a profile ImageField defined.  This is likely the source of your problem.

Answer (score -1):

you are not calling the save method. try this

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AccountView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user  # Pass 'user' directly to the form
        kwargs.save()
```

Comment: form kwargs are a dictionary, they don't have a save method.